# PHP Mysqli insert into database with large iterations

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Below I have Php code that loops through an array and for each it checks if the value already exists in the database and if not, create it. The code itself is working but the loop itself can be insanely big, maximum of a couple tens thousand iterations.

How can I optimize this code? What to use and how to use. There should be a better way to insert this many times without looping through each individual.

```
foreach($arr as $value){
    $checkID = mysqli_query($cenn, "SELECT item_id from items WHERE item_id = '$value'");

    if (!$checkID) {
        die("Query '$checkID' failed to execute for some reason");
    }else{

        if (mysqli_num_rows($checkID) > 0) {
            $user = mysqli_fetch_array($checkID);
            echo "item_id" . checkID . "exists already";
        }
        else{
            echo "item_id: '$user_id' doesn't exist<br>";
            $gw2Api = file_get_contents("https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/items/" . $user_id); //12452 30704
            $gw2Api_result = json_decode($gw2Api,true);

            /*Here would be some code to determine values that are being inserted*/

            if (!array_key_exists("description",$gw2Api_result)) {
                $description = 'No description available...';
            } else{
                if($gw2Api_result['description'] === ''){
                    $description = "No description available...";
                } else {
                    $description = $gw2Api_result['description'];
                }
            }

            $insertItem = "INSERT INTO items 
                             (item_id, name, description, 
                              AccountBindOnUse, AccountBound, 
                              last_update
                             ) 
                      VALUES ('$user_id', '$gw2Api_result[name]', '$description', 
                              '$AccountBindOnUse', '$AccountBound', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";


            if ($cenn->query($insertItem) === true) {
                echo "New record '$user_id' created successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $cenn->error;
            }
        }
    }
} // end foreach
```

The question: How to insert many values, new rows, into mysqli database as fast as possible.

Comment: You might save some time if you used a prepared statement for your INSERT with Parameter markers. Then the INSERT would only need to be compiled and optimised by the database server once rather than 1000's of times

Comment: @RiggsFolly Could you provide some code if possible? Rather new to this all and not quite sure how to begin with what you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Just use bulk insert.
Collect all the rows for insertion and pass it in one query.

```
echo 'hi';
if (!empty($arr)) {
    echo 'ok';
    $values             = "'" . implode("', '", $arr) . "'";
    $qExistingItemIds   = mysqli_query($cenn, "SELECT item_id from items WHERE item_id IN($values)");
    $existingItemIds    = [];
    while ($existingItemId = mysqli_fetch_array($qExistingItemIds)) {
        $existingItemIds[] = $existingItemId['item_id'];
    }

    $arr = array_diff($arr, $existingItemIds);

    $inserts = array();

    $i = 0;
    $ic = count($arr);
    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        $i++;
        echo "item_id: $value doesn't exist<br>";

        $gw2Api = file_get_contents("https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/items/" . $value); //12452 30704
        $gw2Api_result = json_decode($gw2Api,true);

        /*Here would be some code to determine values that are being inserted*/

        if (!array_key_exists("description", $gw2Api_result)) {
            $description = 'No description available...';
        } else {
            if ($gw2Api_result['description'] === '') {
                $description = "No description available...";
            } else {
                $description = $gw2Api_result['description'];
            }
        }

        $inserts[] = "
            ('$value', '$gw2Api_result[name]', '$description', '$AccountBindOnUse', '$AccountBound', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
        ";

        if ($i == 50 OR $i == $ic) {
            $inserts = implode(",", $inserts);
            $insert = "
                INSERT INTO items
                    (item_id, name, description, AccountBindOnUse, AccountBound, last_update)
                VALUES
                    $inserts
            ";

            if ($cenn->query($insert) === true) {
                echo 'great';
                echo "New records created successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $cenn->error;
            }

            $ic -= 50;
            $i = 0;
            $inserts = array();         
        }
    }
}
```

so now we have only 2 queries. not thousands

details about bulk insert:
http://www.geeksengine.com/database/data-manipulation/bulk-insert.php

Comment: Your first code block I am not quite sure how to use. It returns me an error with `mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array given` on line `while ($existingItemId = mysqli_fetch_array($existingItemIds)) {`

Comment: answer fixed. use them one by one

Comment: it can not be the same. unswer updated. just replace your code posted in question with that in answer

Comment: if so, then all data proposed in $arr is already in the table

Comment: Your solution to the problem is sub-par and will probably be rejected by MySQL due to too large packet. This is solved using prepared statements. I suggest showing the example with that instead of a bulk insert query.

Comment: Alright it finally displayed some data but still nothing in my database. Only after a couple minutes it echoed that it had found about 200 Id's not found in the database and it should insert them but nothing is inserted.

Comment: Again it echoed about 200-300 more Ids that are not in the DB(thats good) but nothing inserted. It takes minutes before it again displays a couple hundred at the same time but not inserting.

There are a couple of ten thousands of rows it has to go through. I cant wait for all of them to be done and insert as fast as possible yet keep speed up.

Comment: max_allowed_packet explained in details-link. but anyway lets do the last try. answer updated

Comment: when we talk about thousands i believe prepared statement or not prepared - is not a bottleneck.

Comment: We are talking about tens of thousands of iterations. And it's still not inserting. It does echo unfound ids but not inserting them.

Answer (score 1):

If you use prepared statement you should reduce the round trips to the database server and only compile and optimise each query once instead of Number_of_inputs * 2 queries. This should reduce the workload.

I would be very interested to know by how much.

```
$sql = "SELECT item_id from items WHERE item_id = ?";
$db_select = $cenn->prepare($sql);
if ( ! $db_select ) {
    echo $cenn->error;
    exit;
}

$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO items 
                       (item_id, name, description, 
                        AccountBindOnUse, AccountBound, last_update) 
                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";

$db_insert = $cenn->prepare($sql);
if ( ! $db_insert ) {
    echo $cenn->error;
    exit;
}


foreach($arr as $value){
    $db_select->bind_param('i', $value);
    $res = $db_select->execute()
    if ( $res === FALSE ) {
        echo $cenn->error;
        exit;
    }

    if ($db_select->num_rows > 0) {
        // dont bother fetching data we already know all we need to
        $user = $db_select->free();
        echo "item_id $value exists already";
    } else {
        echo "item_id: $value doesn't exist<br>";
        $gw2Api = file_get_contents("https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/items/" . $value); 
        $gw2Api_result = json_decode($gw2Api,true);

        if ( ! array_key_exists("description",$gw2Api_result)
            || $gw2Api_result['description'] === '') {
            $description = 'No description available...';
        } else{
            $description = $gw2Api_result['description'];
        }


        $db_insert->bind_param('issss', $value, $gw2Api_result[name],
                                        $description, $AccountBindOnUse, 
                                        $AccountBound)

        if ($cenn->query($insertItem) === true) {
            echo "New record $value' created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql_insert . "<br>" . $cenn->error;
        }
    }
} // end foreach
```